# Highlighting slope in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis, slope

I created the slope layer in QGIS through `"Raster > Analysis > Slope"` and then used the function in GRASS `r.slope.aspect`, but how do I highlight a slope of 0° degrees to 60° degrees? I tried the input through the raster calculator `0 < slope < 60` but I obtain a completely black raster without any units.

Comment: Change the display colour for that range of angles in the layer styling panel?

Answer (score 2):

Unless your terrain is very/extremely(?) mountainous you
are not going to have many slopes > 60 degrees, so maybe almost all your slopes are 0-60?

Try:

1. Slope
2. Raster calculator on your slope. I calculate slopes <=30 to 1. Steeper slopes gets value 0.
3. Style the output using "Paletted/Unique values and add only the value 1:

[image]